# Order dropdown item by text

Tags: jquery

I need to order this select to alphabetical ( Already work ) and to the number of names.

This is an example of my `select`:

```
<select id="test" name="test">
   <option value="a">a - 10 names</option>
   <option value="b">b - 17 names</option>
   <option value="c">c - 4 names</option>
</select>
```

Whit this code the  is correct order alphabetical.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnSort').click(function(e) {
    $("#test").html($('#test option').sort(function(x, y) {
        return $(x).text() < $(y).text() ? -1 : 1;
    }))
    $("#test").get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>
```

But how can I order it according to the number of names?

Example:

```
<select id="test" name="test">
   <option value="c">c - 4 names</option>
   <option value="a">a - 10 names</option>
   <option value="b">b - 17 names</option>
</select>
```

I have try this jquery code but don't work:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnSort').click(function(e) {
    $("#test").html($('#test option').sort(function(x, y) {
        return $(x).text().split(' - ') < $(y).text().split(' - ') ? -1 : 1;
    }))
    $("#test").get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>
```

Thanks to all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you split a string like:

```
c - 4 names
```

using:

```
$(x).text().split(' - ')
```

you obtain an array with two values:

- c
- 4 names

If you want to use this strategy you need to consider:

- use x.textContent instead of $(x).text()
- get the second array element
- parse this value

The example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnSort').on('click', function(e) {
    $("#test option").sort(function(x, y) {
      var iX = parseInt(x.textContent.split(' - ')[1]);
      var iY = parseInt(y.textContent.split(' - ')[1]);
      return (isNaN(iX) ? 0 : iX)  - (isNaN(iY) ? 0 : iY);
    }).appendTo('#test');
    $('#test').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" id="btnSort">Sort</button>
<select id="test" name="test">
    <option value="b">b - 17 names</option>
    <option value="c">c - 4 names</option>
    <option value="a">a - 10 names</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have only one number inside option, this sort will work for you:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnSort').click(function(e) {
    $("#test").html($('#test option').sort(function(x, y) {
        return parseInt($(x).text().match(/\d+/g)[0]) < parseInt($(y).text().match(/\d+/g)[0]) ? -1 : 1;
    }))
    $("#test").get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex to find number from string and compare them to short like following.

```js
$('#btnSort').click(function(e) {
    $("#test").html($('#test option').sort(function(x, y) {
          var numX = $(x).text().match(/\d/g).join(''),
              numY = $(y).text().match(/\d/g).join('');
           
          return numX - numY;
    }));
  
  $("#test option").first().prop('selected', true);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test" name="test">  
   <option value="b">b - 17 names</option>
   <option value="c">c - 4 names</option>
   <option value="a">a - 10 names</option>
</select>

<button id="btnSort">Sort</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first grab the number out of option text and then need to compare it as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //get the number out of the option text
  function getNumber(text){
    var arr = text.split(' - ');
    var lastPart = arr[1];
    var numberPart = lastPart.replace(" names","");
    return parseInt(numberPart);
  }
  
  $('#btnSort').click(function(e) {
    $("#test").html($('#test option').sort(function(x, y) {
      return getNumber($(x).text()) < getNumber($(y).text()) ? -1 : 1;
    }))
    $("#test").get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test" name="test">
  <option value="c">e - 14 names</option>
  <option value="a">a - 10 names</option>
  <option value="c">c - 4 names</option>
  <option value="b">b - 17 names</option>
</select>
<button id="btnSort">Sort</button>
```